# UserControl doesn't display inside a window

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

After many searches here and also in tutorials i came up empty handed and would very appreciate help:

I have a UserControl that contains a list of other kind of UserControls.

I want to display this UserControl inside a regular WPF window:

This is the UserControl that contains the list of UserControls:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UsersInfo.InfoLinesContainer"...
...
<Grid>
  <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=InfoLineUC_ObservableList,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">  
  </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And in my main window i do:

```
    <Window x:Class="UsersInfo.MainAppWindow"
    ...
            xmlns:usrCtr ="clr-namespace:UsersInfo"
    ...
    <usrCtr:InfoLinesContainer Grid.Row="11"
                               DataContext="{Binding Path=TheInfoLines, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" 
                               ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" Margin="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Grid.RowSpan="6" />
...
```

TheInfoLines is the instance of the UserControl that contains the list of other UserControls

When i run the program the window comes up without the UserControl inside it(all i get is an empty square)

How can i make it work?

Comment: Have you checked whether your bindings are working?

Answer (score 0):

In your main window :

`<usrCtr:InfoLinesContainer DataContext="{Binding Path=TheInfoLines, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />`

What are you trying to bind here ? There seems to be no ancestor of type UserControl in your window.

Comment: I bind "TheInfoLines" to "_TheInfoLines" which is an instance of the UserControl: "InfoLinesContainer". because i want to add values to it. and then display it with the values i added to it.

Comment: What you are really binding is : the DataContext of your InfoLinesContainer control to an hypothetical "TheInfoLines" property of a "UserControl" which would be a parent of your xaml element <usr:InfoLinesContainer. But its only parent is a Window..